# Piping password to kinit on a windows server

Tags: windows, cmd, kerberos

We are setting up a system where we need to re-verify a user's identify before he/she is allowed to perform a specific task. The user enters his/her password into the website, and then PHP runs kinit to verify that the password is correct. We use Kerberos for authentication. This is what we successfully tried on a Linux server:

```
echo "password123" | kinit username@REALM.COM
```

The problem is that the system is running on a Windows server. We have installed kinit, but cannot seem to get the same thing to work. Running that same command, with or without the quotes, just gives us this output:

```
kinit: Generic preauthentication failure while getting initial credentials
```

Any suggestions on what could be done here?

**Edit:**
Running simply "kinit" and then entering the password at the prompt, works well.

Comment: There is not `base64` in windows; there is `certutil` instead, but it only en/decodes files.

Comment: @double-b Updated now. We have, of course, realised that, and have also tried without base64.

Comment: This won't work. Why don't you try to do it in a single line? Or even `set "var=pw123"` and then `kinit uname@REALM.COM %var%`? I don't see why you need the pipe.

Comment: @double-beep: Because of the risk for command line injection. I cannot escape characters in a password.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this on Windows to pipe password to kinit in batch?